# map matching either at server or client

Tags: android

I am creating an application in android. I need to perform map matching using the data I collected. Which way is better either to perform map matching at server by pushing the data I collected or at client itself having a copy of master data from server?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the amount of data and process time you your dealing with. In a traditional architecture your server should handle all the heavy load, but depending on the requirements you can decide to process it on the client.

Your should ask yourself questions like: How big is your data? What kind of match do you need to do? How expensive is the operation?

Comment: The size would be 5-7 MB of size from server and the GPS data I am collecting would be around 2MB of size on client. I need to map match the collected gps data with geo data from server.

Answer (score 0):

Map Matching should be done on server as it requires some complex computation. Map Box and Google both have their proprietary Map Matching API's. There is open source OSRM Apis as well.

PS: I see this question is 5 years old and mostly people today already know whats the right way to do it